# Valid::not_empty in Kohana 3.1 always passes validation check

Tags: validation, kohana

I have a rule in Kohana 3.1 checking for a non-empty field that always passes the validation check even if empty. `Valid::empty` will not return an error even when the field it's checking is empty, meaning a user could submit an empty form and `$post->check` would return true.

```
$post = Validation::factory($_POST)
    ->rule('username', 'Valid::not_empty');
```

In this example `$post->check()` will pass even when `username` is empty. I do not understand the reason for this. If I am trying to validate a form and fields cannot be left empty a user can submit an empty form and it will pass the validation check.

What is the reason for this behaviour, and what is the best way to achieve the expected result?

Comment: You are aware that ->check() returns a boolean if it's valid or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$post = Validation::factory($_POST)
    ->rule('username', 'not_empty');
```

Just remove "Valid::". :)

Comment: That works, thanks! The documentation is a little misleading: "Rules defined in the Valid class can be added by using the method name alone. The following three rules are equivalent:
$object->rule('number', 'phone');
$object->rule('number', array('Valid', 'phone'));
$object->rule('number', 'Valid::phone');" I thought that carried over for 'not_empty' as well.